# WebSocket handshake failed between JavaScript Client and WCF Service

Tags: javascript, wcf, websocket

I have an existing duplex WCF Web Service which previously used wsDualHttpBinding. I am trying to switch this over to Web Sockets (netHttpBinding) so that it can be used through a web browser client.

I get the following error when trying to instantiate the WebSocket object:

```
WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:8888/CallbackService' failed: Error 
during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 400
```

WCF Config:

```
<system.serviceModel>
<services>
  <service name="CallbackTestWebService">
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8888" />
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
    <endpoint address="CallbackService" binding="netHttpBinding" contract="CallbackTestWebService" />
    <endpoint address="http://localhost:8888/mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
  </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior>
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
</system.serviceModel>
```

JS Code:

```
var url = 'ws://localhost:8888/CallbackService';
var socket = new WebSocket(url); // error
```

I've enabled WCF Tracing - the logs show bytes being received but no errors. The websocket upgrade request in dev tools shows a Bad Request response, representing an unsuccessful upgrade. This is on a Windows 10 machine with IIS 8 and I have checked that the WebSocket Protocol **is** enabled.

The Web Service **does** work with a .NET console client (using `DuplexChannelFactory<>`). I only get this error using JS WebSocket in the browser.

Request/response trace from dev tools:

[image]

How can I solve or obtain more information on this error?

Comment: you try connect to port 8888 but origin is 1646?

Comment: localhost:8888 is where the web service is running, localhost:1646 is the web server that served the client page. Is this a cross-origin problem?

Comment: check if you can connect by using ip instead of localhost. for example ws://192.168.0.1:8888/CallbackService

Comment: @Luke Same error I'm afraid,

Answer (score 0):

This took me quite a bit of time to figure out.  I was able to finally get it working by following this example.
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/619343/Using-WebSocket-in-NET-Part
(scroll down to the "JavaScript in Web Page" section)

I was able to get it to work quite easily with a console application client, but it gave me nothing but trouble trying to connect directly from a browser.  Even after using this example as a reference, the things that tripped me up were:

1.The listener and callback both need to take the Message object as a parameter.  You can't use a primitive type or custom object.  I was able to use a string parameter using the console application.

2.Both methods (listener and callback) need this attribute

```
 [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true, Action = "*")]
```

I played around a little bit and was unable to get this to work with anything but an * for the action.  I'm assuming you can probably specify an action by including it in the url somehow, but I was unable to figure it out.

3.While it might be possible to get it to work using the NetHttpBinding, I was only able to get it to work using the custom binding they use in the example.

4.My url in the javacript code had .svc at the end like so:

```
 new WebSocket("ws://localhost:1234/Service.svc");
```

Without seeing more of your code, it is difficult to provide you with an exact solution to your problem, but I was able to get it to work following this example.